# Why is this lookbehind failing and what does this exception mean?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I'm trying get all ID numbers preceded by some specific text, but it returns nothing followed by an exception (`"Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'" in <function _remove at 0x01F68530> ignored"`)

```
f = open('log.txt')
s = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
a = re.compile('(?<=Activating user record[\s\S]{98})[\w]{15}')
ids = re.findall(a, s)
print ids
```

The pattern works when I test it. If I remove the lookbehind assertion or use another pattern, it's finding matches e.g. re.compile('[\w]{15}'). What am I missing?

I'm trying to snag the 15 character ID from something like this: https://regex101.com/r/1JKo6O/2

Comment: What does your text file look like?

Comment: Try `s = f.read()` and then `ids = re.findall(r'Activating user record[\s\S]{98}(\w{15})', s)`

Comment: @UnbearableLightness I added a snippet of the file.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That gives me the same result.

Comment: On your example line, the regex matches if you replace `{98}` with `{96}`. (Testing with https://regex101.com/)

Comment: @slb why not `re.findall(r"(?<=Activating user record).*?(ID\d+)",str,re.DOTALL)` ?

Comment: Ah right, newlines. Which line is the exception raised on?

Comment: @jfowkes The last line, after it spits out an empty list.

Comment: See http://rextester.com/PJU88858, `r'Activating user record[\s\S]{98}(\w{15})'` works well with `re.findall`, no lookbehind is necessary. If you do not get your matches, you might have `\r\n` endings, try to re-calculate how many `[\s\S]` you need to match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The lookbehind is necessary, I'm only trying to capture the ID at the end. https://regex101.com/r/1JKo6O/2

Comment: No, no lookbehinds are necessary in Python regex since you can simply [**capture** the value](https://regex101.com/r/1JKo6O/4). See the green highlight? That is what `re.findall` returns. Again, check [**this demo**](http://rextester.com/PJU88858).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ahh, thank you!. That pattern works if I'm just using a string like Contents in you example, so there's probably an issue with how I'm reading in this file? I've tried using mmap and the method you suggested earlier.

Comment: I said, use `contents = f.read()`.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, yes I have tried using f.read() as you suggested.

Comment: The answer the question of why there is no match (forgetting the exception), is that when you open the file in `r` mode, [Universal Newlines](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) is stripping the `\r` character from each line, causing the length to be shortened by 2. Using `rb` mode avoids this.

Comment: @jfowkes Perfect! That was exactly what was happening, thank you.